# nodejs gm error when writing image

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to run the example from the node.js gm project to create an image (new.js). I have Windows 7 and GraphicsMagick-1.3.18-Q8 installed.

code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
gm = require('gm'),
dir = __dirname + '/imgs';

gm(525, 110, "#00ff55aa")
  .fontSize(68)
  .stroke("#efe", 2)
  .fill("#555")
  .drawText(20, 72, "graphics")
  .fill("#fa0")
  .drawText(274, 72, " magick")
  .write(dir + '/new.png', function(err){
  if (err) return console.dir(arguments)
    console.log(this.outname + ' created  :: ' + arguments[3])
  }
)
```

error:

```
{ 
    '0': { [Error: Command failed: gm convert: Unable to read font (n019003l.pfb) [Nosuch file or directory].] code: 1, signal: null },
    '1': '',
    '2': 'gm convert: Unable to read font (n019003l.pfb) [No such file or directory].\r\n',
    '3': 'gm "convert" "-size" "525x110" "xc:#00ff55aa" "-pointsize" "68" "-strokewidth" "2" "-stroke" "#efe" "-fill" "#555" "-draw" "text 20,72 \\"graphics\\"" "-fill" "#fa0" "-draw" "text 274,72 \\"magick\\"" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Practice\\youtube/imgs/new.png"' 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've read answers that say to install Ghostscript and I did but nothing changed

Comment: I had that issue to. I had to install ghostscript then actually reinstall graphicsmagick with brew and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 here.

I don't think ghostscript is really necessary as it does not include this font on windows, but the font can be found in github.com/fontforge and placed in working directory.